# How do I add a bearer token to nSwag generated client in a ViewComponent or library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, nswag

I'm using an nSwag generated client to call an API that requires a bearer token to be passed in.

I've setup my client the same as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801655/3953989

I'm calling `SetBearerToken()` in my BaseController's `OnActionExecuting()` and pulling my stored bearer token from a cookie.

`BaseController.cs`

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IApiClient ApiClient;

    public BaseController(IApiClient apiClient)
    {
        ApiClient = apiClient;
    }
    
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CookieData?.Token))
        {
            ApiClient.SetBearerToken(CookieData.Token);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

I also have my ApiClient setup for DI

`Startup.cs`

```
services.AddHttpClient<IApiClient, ApiClient>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(appSettings.Value.ApiBaseUrl);
});
```

This works OK for controllers since `HttpContext` is available during `OnActionExecuting()` but there's no equivalent for ViewComponents.

1. How would I set my bearer token in a ViewComponent?
2. I also would like to know how I should deal with this in libraries that I create in a controllers constructor.

`TestController.cs`

```
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public TestController(IApiClient apiClient) : base(apiClient)
    {
        var cookieData = HttpContext..... // HttpContext is null here
        apiClient.SetBearerToken(cookieData.Token)
    
        _userService = new UserService(apiClient);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can access to HttpContext in the view components. Is why we code in the layouts. There is a lot of information about this if you search here in S.O.

Comment: If you want cookie data from your controller, you can user ```Request.Cookies["name"]```....